# In hadoop hipi, hibimport file support only jpg and png image format, any possible to support all image format in hibImport

Tags: hadoop, image-processing, mapreduce, image-compression, hipi

In hadoop hipi, hibimport file support & importing only jpg and png image format, how to change code for support all image format importing like gif, ppm, bmp, tiff., etc.

And I am trying to recovering high-resolution image from low resolution images .

Answer (score 0):

HIPI supports only 3 image formats i.e JPEG, PNG and PPM. Supported formats are defined here `org.hipi.image.HipiImageHeader.HipiImageFormat`. For details refer this [link](http://hipi.cs.virginia.edu/javadoc/org/hipi/image/HipiImageHeader.HipiImageFormat.html#UNDEFINED)

Comment: Thank you sir. any possible to convert a high-resolution image from low resolution images, blurred images to quality image using hipi.

Comment: possible for image recovery using hipi..?

Comment: If you want to change the size of image in terms of resolution , then Yes it is possible with the OpenCV and HIPI supports OpenCV, but you cannot use other than above 3 image formats.@prakash

Comment: oh, k sir. Thank you.

Comment: but my work is, after decompression of image (hib to jpg r any other format) the image quality is increased and blur image convert to good image quality.

Comment: any possible to work this changes in hipi, where to change this in java code.?

Comment: Than you sir . @mahek